# Reformulate a for loop to use apply in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am currently learning R, and I tried to change a for loop to use apply.
The context is a dataframe galton with 2 variables, parent (hight in inches) and child (height in inches). I want to sample repeatedly from this and get a linear model (using lm) and save that result into a vector.

```
library(UsingR)
sampleLm <- vector(100,mode="list")
for(i in 1:100) {
    sampleGalton <- galton[sample(1:length(galton$child),size=50,replace=F),]
    sampleLm[[i]] <- lm(sampleGalton$child ~ sampleGalton$parent)
}
```

I tried this:

```
sampleLm <- vector(100,mode="list")
sapply(samples, function(x) {
    sampleGalton <- galton[sample(1:length(galton$child),size=50,replace=F),]
    x <- lm(sampleGalton$child ~ sampleGalton$parent)
})
```

the code samples are taken from the galton height of children given parents height.
you can get this data in the UsingR package. This way you get galton. But really it could be anything. just some regular data frame.

but while it executes properly, the `sampleLm` vector isn't updated and contains all `None`. I get the impression this is normal because of the "no side effect" rule I found from the R documentation.

There must be a way to reformulate this so the `for` is replaced with `apply`. The question is how?

Comment: What is `samples`? Please make your code reproducible.

Comment: Why would you expect the second version to modify sampleLm?  I don't see anything that would cause the sapply statement to modify sampleLm.

Comment: with the `apply` family of functions you don't need to create the output variable and fill it like you do in a `for loop`.  instead, assign the output of `sapply` to it:  `sampleLm <- sapply(...)`.

Comment: I am looking to learn R, and I understand for loops are bad, hence my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way here is `replicate`:

```
sampleLm <- replicate(100, lm(child ~ parent, data = galton, 
                              subset = sample(seq(nrow(galton)), size = 50)), 
                      simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sven! That's exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to preallocate sampleLm when using the *apply family.  You just need to write the function you want to run so that it turns the result of interest and then store the final result in a variable.

```
sampleLm <- sapply(samples, function(x) {
    sampleGalton <- galton[sample(1:length(galton$child),size=50,replace=F),]
    lm(sampleGalton$child ~ sampleGalton$parent)
})
```